# Can a facebook app get friends of an app user with app access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

From the documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ it seems that to fetch user's friends one needs users valid access token.

But it appears that I can fetch the ids of app user's friends even with app access token. Since it is undocumented I am not sure if it is by design or it is working only for my app / time being.

Comment: As long as the user has authorized your app, you can get his friends with either his user access token or the app token. Not authorized == no friends available via app token.

Comment: Can I also access all the details of the friends for which the user has given permissions to the app with the app access token? I am not 100% sure but long back I think had seen that the fields that can be fetched with app token were limited vs fields fetched with user's access token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can can get an app user's friends with an app token. This is documented under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

> While an App Access Token is largely for the purposes of publishing information back to Facebook on behalf of the user, there is a limited set of information that can be retrieved from Facebook using an App Access Token.
>
> - Basic Profile Info of a User (ID, Name, Username, Gender)
> - A User’s Friends and their IDs
> - Permissions granted by the User to your App